# Checkout page header is not coming

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, header, footer

I have made a custom theme in magento 2 all is doing well but in the customer checkout page i don't get my header footer is there but the header is missing. can anyone help me to get out of this.

Comment: In Magento 2 (default) header is not displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in default magento 2 there is no header and footer in checkout page but if you want to add it custom way then please follow below steps:

First go to Magento_Checkout in your theme folder `app/design/frontend/theme package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout`

Now create below folder structure in layout folder on above path. `override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml`

in this checkout_index_index.xml file add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
   </body>
  </page>
```

Comment: I did the way you told me. But i did not get any result after doing this. The problem is still same.

Comment: Have you cleared cache ? @karanmahajan

Comment: Admin cache or browser cache?

Comment: i have cleared all cache but yet i don't get header on checkout page. please get me out of this

Comment: Ok check the things like have you placed file in proper location(in working theme folder) also check name(spelling) of folder and files then remove cache and page_cache folder from root=>var directory. now check checkout page @karanmahajan

Comment: when i put folder structure in layout folder of custom theme override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml. i get error (/home/glamrina/public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/glamrina/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files.)

Comment: thank you for your response. the header is now coming in checkout page.

Comment: Most welcome. You can vote and accept my answer if you found it useful. It will be helpful for others thanks @karanmahajan

Comment: i have a query that when i added checkout layout in custom theme the payment gateways are not coming any idea ??

Comment: go to Store->Configuration->Sales->Payment Method->Cash on Delivery Payment ->Enabled->YES .clear cache, and then go and check checkout page. Now check is it working ? @karanmahajan

Comment: @karanmahajan How did you solve ""checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files" error?

Comment: @Mahesh have you check here 
"/var/www/html/mage212/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout"